# How to properly mount b-table component in vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vue-test-utils, buefy

I am using `buefy` css lib along with `vue.js` framework.

I am trying to unit test my vue component (`Foo`) which has `b-table` component from `buefy`:

```
<b-table :data="foo" class="container" style="width: 50%">
        <b-table-column v-slot="props">
            <b-icon
                pack="fas"
                icon="times"
                class="is-clickable"
                @click.native="doSomething(props.row)"
            ></b-icon>
        </b-table-column>
</b-table>
```

*note the embedded `b-icon`*

In `Foo.spec.js` test file I am trying to mount the component using `shallowMount` from `vue-test-utils`:

```
import Buefy from "buefy";
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Foo from './Foo.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Buefy);

const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo, {
    localVue,
});
```

Now I would like to use the returned wrapper to perform some actions on `b-icon` which should be embedded in the table column.

```
const icon = wrapper.find('.is-clickable')

icon.vm.$emit('click')
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined
```

The thing is, that this `b-icon` is in fact missing in the wrapper. It can be confirmed via `wrapper.html()`:

```
<b-table-stub data="[object Object],[object Object]" columns="" headercheckable="true" checkboxposition="left" isrowselectable="[Function]" isrowcheckable="[Function]" checkedrows="" mobilecards="true" defaultsortdirection="asc" sorticon="arrow-up" sorticonsize="is-small" sortmultipledata="" currentpage="1" perpage="20" showdetailicon="true" paginationposition="bottom" rowclass="[Function]" openeddetailed="" hasdetailedvisible="[Function]" detailkey="" detailtransition="" total="0" filtersevent="" showheader="true" class="container" style="width: 50%;">
      <b-table-column-stub visible="true" thattrs="[Function]" tdattrs="[Function]"></b-table-column-stub>
</b-table-stub>
```

`b-icon` has magically disappeared.

Fully mounting via `mount` is not helpfull either:

```
<div class="b-table container" style="width: 50%;">
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <div class="table-wrapper has-mobile-cards">
        <table class="table">
          <!---->
          <tbody>
            <tr draggable="false" class="">
              <!---->
              <!---->
              <!---->
            </tr>
            <transition-stub name="">
              <!---->
            </transition-stub>
            <!---->
            <tr draggable="false" class="">
              <!---->
              <!---->
              <!---->
            </tr>
            <transition-stub name="">
              <!---->
            </transition-stub>
            <!---->
            <!---->
          </tbody>
          <!---->
        </table>
        <!---->
      </div>
      <!---->
</div>
```

How can I access data / components embedded in the table columns?

`b-table` documentation: [link](https://buefy.org/documentation/table)

`b-table` source code: [link](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/table/Table.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `shallowMount` but stub `b-table-column` yourself like this:

```
const BTableColumnStub = {
  template: <span class="b-table-column-super-stub"><slot name="props"></slot></span>
}

const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo, {
  localVue,
  stubs: {
    BTableColumn: BTableColumnStub  
  }
});
```

`BIcon` in your component is passed as named slot `props`. Default Jest`s stubbing just stubs component not taking slots into account. I think that should help to render `BIcon`.

And btw, if you want to trigger `click` event, you should call
`await icon.trigger('click')` not `icon.vm.$emit('click')`. But to test event listener you also can call `wrapper.vm.$emit('your-event')` , I mean you should call `$emit` on the component that is listening to that event, not on the one that would emit that event.

Comment: I had to quote the 'template' contents, otherwise the exception is raised. Nevertheless, `b-table-column` become stubbed as expected but no icon is rendered still unfortunately. The `<slot>` is not rendered as well. In the `b-table` source code I can't find the `<slot name=props>` anywhere - that's might be the clue.

Answer (score 0):

b-table has child components.
You may try to use mount instead of shallowMount.
That will render b-table.